# Bazel cc_library with no srcs doesn't compile on its own

Tags: c++, bazel

I have a cc_library that is header-only. Whenever I try to compile such library by itself, it won't actually compile anything. I purposely put some errors to try to get such errors on compilation, but bazel doesn't actually compile anything. Here's a small example.

```cpp
// test.h

This should not compile fdsafdsafdsa
int foo() { return 1; }
```

```py
# BUILD

cc_library(
  name = 'test',
  hdrs = ['test.h']
)
```

```
// bazel build :test
INFO: Analyzed target //:test (2 packages loaded, 3 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //:test up-to-date (nothing to build)
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.083s, Critical Path: 0.00s
INFO: 0 processes.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
```

Is this behavior intended?

I also ran the same experiment but splitting the .h and .cc files, and in that case, I got the error when I compiled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cc_library` (other rules as well incl. `pkg_tar` for instance) does not have to have any sources. This is also valid:

```
cc_library(
    name = "empty",
    srcs = [],
)
```

And it is actually quite useful too. You may have configurable attributes such as `deps` (or `srcs`) where actual content is only applicable for certain conditions:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "mybinary",
    srcs = ["main.c"],
    deps = select({
        ":platform1": [":some_plat1_only_lib"],
        ":platform2": [":empty"],  # as defined in the above snippet
    }),
)
```

Or (since above you could have just as well used `[]` for `:platform2` `deps`) where you have a larger tree and you expect developers to just depend on `//somelib:somelib`, you could use this empty library through an `alias` to give them a single label without having to worry about all the platform specific details and how providing certain function is handled where:

```
# somelib/BUILD:
alias(
    name = "somelib",
    actual = select({
        ":platform1": [":some_plat1_only_lib"],
        ":platform2": [":empty"],  # as defined in the above snippet
    }),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],  # set appropriately
)
```

And `mybinary` or any other target could now say:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "mybinary",
    srcs = ["main.c"],
    deps = ["//somelib"],
)
```

And of course, as the other answer here states, there are header only libraries.

Also in the example you've used in your question. (`bazel` or not) you would normally not (and it would not be very useful either) compile a header file on its own. You would only use its content and only then see the compiler fails as you attempt to build a source the header is `#include`d from. That is for `bazel build` to fail, another target would have to depend on `test` and `#include "test.h"`.

Answer (score 2):

A header only library means that you don't need to build anything. Simply include the headers you need in your program and use them.

Comment: That's fair. However, it caught me off guard because I sometimes want to build the library just for the sake of checking for errors. But when I did so, I expected to see some errors but got none instead.